# C# delimiting string parts and saving to variables

Tags: string, delimiter

I have this string received from Tuple:

```
"(ConnectionString|EEE99|, OutlookSenderTo|eda@test.com; e@ee.com|)";
```

So what I need is to save string parts btween || into other string variables, e.g.:

```
string str1 = EEE99;
string str2 = eda@test.com; e@ee.com;
```

Any ideas how this could be reached? I guess the simpliest way will be to use LINQ here? I tried delimiting the whole string

```
string[] words = str.Split('|');
```

But it gives a lot of unnecessary lines with ',' or some others.

Answer (score 0):

Found some solution:

```
string pattern = @"\|([^\|]*)\|";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, pattern);
```

Will give:
|EEE99|
|eda@test.com; e@ee.com|

To remove fist and last characters, simply use

```
Trim('|');
```